# Yii2 Update the DataProvider of a Listview after Ajax

Tags: php, yii2

I try without success to update the DataProvider of a listview when i submit a form through Ajax. It is working when i submit without ajax, but refresh the page. I would like to do it without refreshing the page. I don t know what exactly could be wrong in my code below:

Here is the form and the listview:

**jobs.php**

```
...

<div style="background-color: white;">

<div class="job_quick_search_container">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'quick_search_form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal', 
                      'onkeypress'=>" if(event.keyCode == 13){ searchJob(); }" 
                     ],
    ]); ?>

    <table style="width:100%">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:20%">
            <col style="width:20%">
            <col style="width:20%">
            <col style="width:40%">
        </colgroup>

        <tr>    
            <td style="padding-right: 50px;">
                 <?= $form->field($jobCompanyCategorySearchModel, 'ccCategory')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Companycategory::find()->all(),'ccID', 'ccCategory'), ['prompt'=>'Select a category'] ) 
                 ?>                 
            </td>

            <td style="padding-right: 50px;">
                <?= $form->field($jobUserSearchModel, 'uCountry')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),
                                                                     'uCountry', 'uCountry'),
                                                                     ['prompt'=>'Select a country'] ) 
                ?>
            </td>

            <td style="padding-right: 50px;">
                <?= $form->field($jobUserSearchModel, 'uCompanyName')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),
                                                                     'uCompanyName', 'uCompanyName'),
                                                                     ['prompt'=>'Select a company'] ) 
                ?>
            </td>

            <td>


                <div class="form-group">
                   <?= Html::Button('Find a job', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
                                                   'onclick' => 'searchJob();',  
                                                   'style' => 'font-size:18px']) ?>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>    

</div>


<table style="width:100%">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:65%">
        <col style="width:35%">
    </colgroup>

    <tr>
        <td>
             //This partial view contains the listview
            <?= $this->render( 'jobs_partial_view', ['dataProvider'=> $dataProvider] ); ?>

        </td>
  ...
```

The partial view: **jobs_partial_view.php**

```
<?php
   use yii\widgets\ListView;
?>

<div class="jobs_listView_container">

    <?= 
        ListView::widget([

            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'options' => [
                            'tag' => 'div',
                            'class' => 'list_jobs_profile',
                            'id' => 'list_jobs_profile',
                        ],
            'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}",

            'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return $this->render('_job_view',['model' => $model]);
            },

            'itemOptions' => [
                'tag' => false,
            ],

            'pager' => [
                'firstPageLabel' => 'first',
                'lastPageLabel' => 'last',
                'nextPageLabel' => 'next',
                'prevPageLabel' => 'previous',
                'maxButtonCount' => 3,
            ],

            'emptyText' => "Sorry, No jobs found",

        ]);
    ?>
```

Here ist the **Jquery function using Ajax**:

```
function searchJob(){

var seach_data_job = $("#quick_search_form").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'jobs',
    data: seach_data_job,
    dataType: 'html',

    success: function(e) {

    },

    /*

    error: function(response, status){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(status);
    }

    */
});

return false;
}
```

Here **the Controller**:

```
public function actionJobs()
{

      $jobCompanyCategorySearchModel = new JobCompanycategorySearch();
      $jobUserSearchModel = new JobUserSearch();

     if (  $jobUserSearchModel->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) && 
          $jobCompanyCategorySearchModel->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) ) {


        $idCategorySearch = $jobCompanyCategorySearchModel->ccCategory;
        $companyNameSearch = $jobUserSearchModel->uCompanyName;
        $companyCountrySearch = $jobUserSearchModel->uCountry;

         $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => Jobs::find()->where(['jCategory' => $idCategorySearch])
                                       ->orderBy('jID DESC'), 
                'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 10,],
            ]);

         echo $this->renderPartial( 'jobs_partial_view', 
                                                ['jobCompanyCategorySearchModel' => $jobCompanyCategorySearchModel,
                                                 'jobUserSearchModel' => $jobUserSearchModel,
                                                 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
                                                ] );
    } 

  else {


      $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Jobs::find()->orderBy('jID DESC'),  
            'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 10,],
        ]);

     return $this->render('jobs', ['jobCompanyCategorySearchModel' => $jobCompanyCategorySearchModel,
                                          'jobUserSearchModel' => $jobUserSearchModel,
                                          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
                                          ] );
   }

       }
```

After submitting the forms through Ajax, i get the data in the controller, but the funtion renderPartial is not updating the view with the new dataProvider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found myself the solution of my problem, but it could help the next readers.

Everything is perfect in the dataprovider and the ajax submit. What i didn't know before is that, after updating the Dataprovider and calling the function renderPartial(),

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Jobs::find()->where(['jCategory' => $idCategorySearch])
                           ->orderBy('jID DESC'), 
    'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 10,],
 ]);

 echo $this->renderPartial( 'jobs_partial_view', 
                            ['jobCompanyCategorySearchModel' => $jobCompanyCategorySearchModel,
                             'jobUserSearchModel' => $jobUserSearchModel,
                             'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
                            ] );
```

I could get the view (The new Listview) in response of Ajax using jQuery and load it in the html content of the old list view's container:

```
function searchJob(){

var form = $("#quick_search_form");
var search_data_job = form.serialize();

var partialviewcontainer = $("#jobs_partial_view_container");

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'jobs',
    data: search_data_job,
    dataType: 'html',

    success: function(newPartialView) {
                 partialviewcontainer.html(newPartialView);
             },

});

return false;

 }
```

I have added the **fadeIn** and **fadeOut** functions to make the Reload smooth.

From:

```
partialviewcontainer.html(newPartialView);
```

To:

```
 $(partialviewcontainer).fadeOut(800, function(){                      
      partialviewcontainer.html(newPartialView).fadeIn().delay(2000);
 });
```

Hope it will help.

Thanks to people who have tried to help me too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Pjax in your case. So your from will be like below.

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST']]); ?>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'id' => 'quick_search_form',
      'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
      'enableClientValidation'=>true,
      'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal']
    ]); ?>
        .......
        .......
        <!-- your form htmls will goes here -->
        .......
        .......
    <?php \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <?= $this->render( 'jobs_partial_view', ['dataProvider'=> $dataProvider] ); ?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**Note:** you no need to write ajax code for form submission. Pjax will take case of all ajax stuffs. Also you have to merge your two controller actions - `actionJobs`, `actionJobsearch` into single action. So all `actionJobsearch` coding will come inside `actionJobs`.

Comment: I tried Pjax before to solve this issue without success.

Comment: @stfsngue is it! Can you update your question with your Pjax code? So it will help to resolve your problem.

Comment: @stfsngue you have to merge your controller actions into single as I mention in my answer. Please check.

Comment: Ok I will edit the controller now. But I tried it before too.

Comment: Ok I have just edited the controller and the jquery function. But still not working.

Comment: @stfsngue you can remove 'onkeypress' event from your form now. You no need to write ajax code, Pjax will take care of it. I hope I already mention in my answer ;)